# Node.js v18.13.0 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... - How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, backend, mern

I'm trying to clone whatsapp.. I've done with frontend part.. but when I try to connect with mongodb and get & post a request through postman api... but my code is getting crashed.

I'm using "type":"module" in package.json

This is what i'm getting in terminal

```
Listening on localhost:9000
D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:282
        throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')} ${isOrAre} not supported`);
              ^

MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
    at parseOptions (D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:282:15)
    at new MongoClient (D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:45:63)
    at D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:802:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.openUri (D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:799:19)
    at D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:409:10
    at D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)       
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\Project\Guvi\Task\React\clone-whatsapp\wa-back\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1262:10) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.13.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Messages from './dbMessages.js';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.use(express.json());

const connection_url =        'mongodb+srv://sarath_babayaga:Sarath@1996@cluster0.wzoouq0.mongodb.net/clone-whatsapp-backend?  retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(connection_url,{
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.status(200).send('hello world!!!!'));

app.get('/messages/sync', (req, res) => {
    const dbMessage = req.body

    Messages.find ((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data)
        }
    })
})


app.post('/messages/new', (req, res) => {
    const dbMessage = req.body

    Messages.create(dbMessage, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        } else {
            res.status(201).send(data)
        }
    })
})

app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Listening on localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: It seems you are using a deprecated option (useCreateIndex). What version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: Hi Cristian, I'm using the mongoose 6.8.3 version

Comment: And i'm also using using useCreateIndex

Answer (score 0):

according to the official forum of MongoDB, UseCreateIndex is deprecated since Mongoose 6, so I think this is the issue. Try removing useCreateIndex from your code

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/option-usecreateindex-is-not-supported/123048/3